# invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml, encoding

I am trying to parse an XML file with `<?version = 1.0, encoding = UTF-8>`
but ran into an error message `invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence`. Does anybody know what caused this problem?

Comment: how are you parsing the xml file?

Answer (score 25):

Most commonly it's due to feeding `ISO-8859-x` (Latin-x, like Latin-1) but parser thinking it is getting `UTF-8`. Certain sequences of Latin-1 characters (two consecutive characters with accents or umlauts) form something that is invalid as `UTF-8`, and specifically such that based on first byte, second byte has unexpected high-order bits.

This can easily occur when some process dumps out `XML` using Latin-1, but either forgets to output `XML` declaration (in which case `XML` parser must default to `UTF-8`, as per `XML` specs), or claims it's `UTF-8` even when it isn't.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix that? I ran into this problem when defining an ant task using the 3rd party library XMLTask.

Comment: That is tough then; otherwise what is usually done is explicitly create an InputStreamReader for specific encoding, then give that to XML parser. But not sure what to do with Ant... aside from fixing XML file itself of course, if possible.

Comment: I figured out the problem - In one of my xml's I had an Umlaut (ä, ö, ü) which somehow got screwed up when I converted the xml file into different formats. Once I removed that Umlaut it worked out.

Comment: Right -- those characters are single byte with Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) and 2 bytes in UTF-8. So content was in Latin-1, but something somewhere claimed it would be in UTF-8.

Answer (score 7):

You could try to change default character encoding used by String.getBytes() to utf-8. Use VM option -Dfile.encoding=utf-8.

Answer (score 6):

Either the parser is set for UTF-8 even though the file is encoded otherwise, or the file is declared as using UTF-8 but it really doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. My problem was that I created a new XML file with jdom and the *FileWriter(xmlFile)*. The FileWriter was not able to create a UTF-8 File.
Instead using the **FileOutputStream(xmlFile)** solved it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem too when trying import my .xml file into my java tool. And I found a good solution for this:
1. Open the .xml file with Notepad++ then save the .xml file as .rtf file. Then open this file in WordPad application. 
2. Save the .rtf file as .txt file, then open it with Notepad, and save it as .xml file again. When saving in Notepad, near the end of the pop-up window, make sure choosing the option "Encoding: UTF-8".
It worked for mine, hope it's useful for yours too.

Answer (score 2):

For those who still get such mistake.

since UTF-8 is being used check out your xml document for any latin letters or so:
I had the same problem and the reason was i had this:

```
<n:name>Åke Jógvan Øyvind</n:name>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The switching of the encoding for the input might help in this case:

```
XMLEventReader eventReader =
                            inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in, 
                                    "utf-8"
                                    //"windows-1251"
                            );
```